# How to connect remotely to mongodb using Compass when remote server has SSL (https)

Tags: mongodb, ssl, ufw

I followed online guides to connect to mongodb (version 4.0) using Compass but I get below error:

MongoDB not running on the provided host and port

Assume remote server is running on https://example.com that has IP address 
172.231.151.42

On Compass I enter hostname as 172.231.151.42
and port 27017. All other settings are default (like Authentication None SSL None  SSH Tunnel None).

On remote ubuntu server where mongod is running I configured UFW rule

ufw allow from 201.12.62.17 to any port 27017

where 201.12.62.17 is public IP of my desktop mac laptop.

In mongodb.conf  I have below line:

bindIp: 127.0.0.1,201.12.62.17

to allow connections  from laptop.

No user and password is setup for mongodb. Any one can access mongodb.

But still I am getting error.

Do I need to do something about SSL?

What I am missing?

Comment: same issue I am facing.

Comment: How you were able to resolve this